# how to put name to columns to one jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jtableheader

```
public void fillTable()
{
  conexiones.daofutbolista search = new conexiones.daofutbolista();
  ResultSet datostraidos =search.buscarfutbolistas(); 

  try
  {
    model.addColumn("numero"); 
    model.addColumn("equipo"); 
    model.addColumn("posicion");
    model.addColumn("Numero"); 
    model.addColumn("apodo"); 
    model.addColumn("Liguilla");
    model.addColumn("Edad");  
    while(datostraidos.next() )
    {
      Object [] fila = new Object[7];
      for(int i=0;i<7;i++) 
      {
        fila[i]=datostraidos.getObject(i+1);
        System.out.println("for");
      }
      System.out.println("while");
      model.addRow(fila);
    }
    model.addRow(columnasname);
    gridview.setModel(model);
  }
  catch(Exception es)
  {
    System.out.println(es);
  }
}
```

i have that method for fill my jtable with a query but my jtable' columns don't have a name, how do i put it? i dont want to delete the query gotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your table model looks like? 
Are you using a default table model?

Also, do you use a JSCrollPane? If not, adding it to a JSCrollPane works most of the times.

See this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show

In this code I have two tables, one with JScrollPane, one without.

Look how the second (placed at the bottom) doesn't have headers.

By the way, this is a nice trick to provide a "results" column ;)

[image: using scrollpane]

Comment: Yes, I think you just need to put the table in a scrollpane, or get the table header and manually place it on the gui.

Comment: i do use a defaulttablemodel it is MODELO

Comment: but why do i need a scrollpane? i just wanna my table' columns have names

Comment: Because the jscrollpane layout the table header which otherwise doesn't show. BTW I change subtly your source code just to provide the chance from other to get it better.